# Finding stored procedures with errors in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a database which consists of almost 200 tables and 3000 stored procedures.

I have deleted some fields from some tables, how can I now find stored procedures in which those deleted fields are referred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

So in your case, you could type in the column name you deleted, and select to search only your stored procedures - and within a second or so, you'll have a list of all stored procs that contain that particular column name. Absolutely great stuff!

Comment: It's free? We have Red Gate licenses so never checked... :-)

Comment: @gbn: it's **absolutely, totally, utterly** - **F-R-E-E** ! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx)

```
SELECT
   OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM
   sys.sql_modules
WHERE
   definitiion LIKE '%MyDeletedColumn%'
```

Or [OBJECT_DEFINITION](http://OBJECT_DEFINITION)

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are unreliable for this because the definition is split over several nvarchar(4000) rows. The 2 methods above return nvarchar(max)

Edit: Given SQL Search is free as note by marc_s, this will a better solution.

Comment: A simpler approach, and probably the one I'd use if the column was called 'my_highly_unique_column'.  :)  Definitely worth a +1.

Comment: @Will A: You can hedge your bets if your schema for things like ".MyDeletedColumn" or "MyDeletedColumn " YMMV of course. And thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
select object_name(object_id), *
from sys.sql_module
where definition like '%ColName%'
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to call each stored procedure with dummy parameters with `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON` active.  This won't run the procedure, but will generate an .xml representation of the plan - and will fail if referenced columns are missing.  If you make use of #temp tables, however, this'll fail regardless.  :(

You'd most likely want to automate this process, rather than writing out 3000 procedure calls.

DISCLAIMER: This isn't a bulletproof approach to picking up on missing columns, but good luck finding anything better!

Comment: Check out the free SQL Search - **much better** way of finding stuff in SQL Server...